# UML State Machine Diagram - How to model an event that occours repeatedly

Tags: uml, modeling, finite-state-machine

I'm trying to model the evolution of a player's *energy* in a game.

- I have an "alive" state, and a transition to it from the initial pseudostate that has the effect of setting the initial energy to 100:

> `(initial) ---( / energy = 100 )--> (Alive)`

- The player loses 1 energy point for each step he takes which I modeled with a self-transition:

> `(Alive) ---( when (step) / energy -= 1 )--> (Alive)`

- If the player *doesn't move* for 3 minutes, they should lose 2 energy points
- Every 15 minutes, the player gains 10 energy points.

I'm not sure how I should represent these last two. My initial, naive idea was to use an `after (3 min)` self-transition, but that would mean that the system actively waits for the time to pass, so it's wrong.

One suggestion I received is that I should have an external "trigger", and make use of internal and external activities.

**Edit**: I should add, for completeness, that there is an additional transition to the final pseudostate when the player's energy reaches zero.

Comment: Are you sure you should be modeling this on a state diagram? It seems like the object is still in an `Alive` state, but that other things are happening. Perhaps a timing or activity diagram is more suited to what you want to model?

Comment: @ThomasOwens I've been asked to use a state diagram, specifically, although I do recognise that other diagrams may be more appropriate

Comment: I would ask why you're being asked to use a state diagram - which seems to be an inappropriate diagram type for communicating this information - over other diagram types which are designed to communicate this information. It tends to be seen as a good practice to use the right tool for the job.

Comment: @ThomasOwens which I would indeed do, were I asked about this in the workplace. However, this question has been asked by my Software Engineering professor in class. Also, abstracting away from the example, I think there may be cases in which modeling this sort of repetition in a state machine diagram (maybe one with more states) might not be a bad idea..

Comment: `I've been asked to use a state diagram` It doesn't mean that you got right what to do. If your teacher asked you for a state diagram, then the last 2 points are out of the diagram. The state diagram only shows possible/allowed state transitions. In this case, Player's state transitions. Schedules and conditions are irrelevant. They can be side notes or comments.

Comment: @Laiv I'm fairly confident I understood correctly, since I spoke with the professor in person, and showed them what I had done in VP. The only suggestion they gave me was that "the waiting should be modeled as an external activity", and they told me I might want to put everything I have inside of a compound state (although I'll admit they were a big vague). Are you suggesting that what I was asked to model cannot be expressed at all with this choice of diagram?

Comment: Course work is very different than the real world. You'll probably have to work with your professor on this. We don't know what your professor is looking for. I know that it is an inappropriate use of UML state diagrams. Perhaps there's a non-UML solution or something else that your professor wants. Seeking help from us likely won't result in something that aligns with your professor's expectations.

Comment: Maybe the alive state is compound with moving and stationary internal states?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

State diagrams are indeed an effective way to model the event-driven behavior of a single object.

#### Relative time event

The relative time interval `after(3 minutes)` requires the player to not move.  Whenever the player moves, for example making a step,  the interval is reset.

The easiest way to model this is a self-transition for the move events, and a self-transition for the timing event.  This way, every move re-enters the state and the timer starts anew.

**Important remark**:  the `after(delay)` does specify a time related event.  It does not impose any way to implement such an event. In other words, you are not forced to actively (and inefficiently) monitor the passing time, and could very well use some efficient timer event of your OS.

#### Repetitive time event

The "every 15 minutes" is also a relative time event, that could be expressed with `after(15 minutes)`.  It's just that its count-down cannot be disturbed by any other state transition.

One way of modeling this, would indeed be to have a separate very simple state diagram for an object that would send the periodic events, e.g. `Tick15` to the Player object. In your state machine, you would then react to such a `Tick15` event with the appropriate transition. The inconvenience is that you loose the oversight (and have a more complex model with more objects).

A typical alternative is to keep the logic in your single object and use a [composite state](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.2/model_domains/compositestate.html) with nested orthogonal state machines.  This allows **separation of concerns**: One orthogonal region would model the lifecycle around an `Alive` state, and would only capture the repetitive time events. Another orthogonal region would be for tracking movement-related events around an `Idle` state.

#### Other tips

Instead of going directly from `Alive` to the pseudo-end-state, you may prefer to add a state `Dead` that could care for things such as showing some animation of the player's end, showing the game score, or whatever. This state would then fire a transition to the pseudo-end-state upon its completion (outgoing arrow without any event).

The `when(condition)` expresses a change event if the condition is true.  So you'd typically use it to detect the end of the game:  `when(energy<=0)`.  But you would not use it for `when(step)` since it's not about a boolean expression.  If `step` is an event,  just write `step`.

#### Wrap-up

The diagram could look like:

[image]

[Plantuml url](https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/png/VP0npu8m48Rt_ehRFlWC4JGkH0mcBcucZiQXIKybATMK8Y7YV_VWaeeEJjmTJv_slRnoqhgwrEBmVuHe1JijMxHx9nr22bD0W_RSJh8aZaKrJ3Se5PSVy4C0y7IhD5BprtyX8cT_WcJD1Kt0lcKMXuGmeQwD8MfeKdBWRNolnzw8F3cqmHpAmjGEgz3ZKJOZlElyKzQwk2DGomKvkFAIPF5juR12FCKutOyO_NZuJniKEHf5stm1)

(At any given time, each orthogonal region has one active state, so `Alive` and `Idle` are active at the same time, each having independent state transitions, until a transition of the enclosing composite state is fired)

Comment: I have some doubts. I miss some info here. For example. What's the initial state? Idle or Alive? What are the supported transitions between Idle and Alive? What are the possible transitions between those 2 and `Dead`?  What does mean `step`? If step means activity, then why the Player remains `Idle`? Wouldn't `idle` be a substate of `alive`? Etc...

Comment: @Laiv Thanks for the opportunity to clarify: when entering the composite state PlayerState, each orthogonal region represents a nested state machine having each one active state at the same time (sorry if plantuml doesn’t render the dashed region separator nicely). For more info: https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.2/model_domains/compositestate.html - in case of any residual doubt, see the UML 2.5.1 specifications.

Comment: Good point. The UML spec also matters. I'm quite outdated when it comes to UML notation.